# What do $d\phi$ and $\in$ mean in terms of probability

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm reading Peter Orbanz's notes on Bayesian nonparametrics http://stat.columbia.edu/~porbanz/papers/porbanz_BNP_draft.pdf.  In it, he uses the following notation, which isn't defined.

We have some Dirac measure $\delta_{\phi_{k}}$, the atoms of a probability (mixing) measure
\begin{align}
\theta(\cdot)&=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}c_{k}\delta_{\phi_{k}}(\cdot)
\end{align}
with atom locations $\phi_{k}$.

We also have
\begin{align}
\Theta&=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}C_{k}\delta_{\Phi_{k}}
\end{align}

We want to calculate 
\begin{align}
P(\Phi_{i}\in d\phi|...)\\
P(\phi_{i}\in \cdot)
\end{align}

I don't understand the following in terms of notation

- What does $\in d\phi$ mean?  Particularly, what does $d\phi$ mean in this setting?  I also see a distribution $G$, and they write $G(d\phi)$, which seems to indicate that $G$ is parametrized by $d\phi$, but I'm not sure.
- What does $\cdot$ mean as used in $\theta(\cdot)$ and $\in \cdot$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

$d\phi$ is just notation: my guess from context is that $P(\Phi \in d \phi \mid \dots)$ is a conditional density of the random variable $\Phi$, which we informally interpret as the probability that it falls in $[\phi,\phi+d\phi]$ divided by $d\phi$.

$\cdot$ in this context means "one of the independent variables of the function". It is most commonly used to define functions from more complicated functions in "point-free style". For example, $g=f(y,\cdot)$ means the same thing as $g(x)=f(y,x)$.